# CSS property of nested class `.divy` to cover 100% of `body`?

Tags: html, css

html (jade)

```
body
 .divx
  .divy
```

Given css:

```
.divx {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

What css property of class `.divy` will make it cover 100% width and height of `body`?

If i make

```
.divy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The above makes `.divy` cover 100% of `.divx` not `body`

Comment: Why is .divy nested within .divx if it's to be removed from that context to fill the entire body?

Comment: Use absolute positioning

Comment: Nesting the element makes it relative to its parent. You can simply apply position: absolute; to pull it from the nested context and make it relative to the body.

Comment: This is expected behaviour...if you want the `.divy` element to be 100% of body it shouldn't be in a container. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Joucks I made source example here for you http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/pkrsg  so I belive that's the anwser.

Comment: use `,`, separate them in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position `absolute`

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8rtYQ/1/)</kbd>

```
.divy {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```